# Limit the url boundary in UITextView

Tags: hyperlink, click, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have used NSAttributedString in my UITextView, some links are there, however when I touch the screen where is not right on the link but close to it, it will response to my click on the link. How can I limit the boundary of it so that I can touch the position around the link and not get the response.

also I want to know that when user regret their click on the link, and move their finger out of the position of the link, the link also response to the link, how can I return no response when user tap on the link but move to another position and take back their finger?

Comment: Yep I have the same problem. Anything near the link makes the link open. Did you find anything?